# Dryer not turning on. Potential component isn't getting a Ohm (200) or continuity reading. Next steps?

Tags: electrical, dryer

My issue can be a bit lengthy and I am learning this as I go as well. I don't do any electric work and just want to do more DIY to fix things around the house.

From checking on youtube there were some common issues to check why the dryer would not be working.

I have checked the power button circuit and the thermal fuse. I used a multimeter's continuity setting and got readings of > +1. I also tried Ohms 200 and got on average 0.06 reading.

I have checked the power outlet and it is giving off proper voltage. Unsure what else to do I decided to check continuity and ohm reading from a bunch of different components. One such component stood out.

[image: dryer component]

I measured at the purple wires and I got no change in reading for continuity and Ohm (200). While all other components in the back of the dryer got a change in the reading.

What are my next steps?
Replace the component? Are the wires bad?

Edit:

Inglis Dryer IGD4400VQ1

I believe this is the component [Dryer Cycling Thermostat](https://www.partselect.com/PS11741405-Whirlpool-WP3387134-Dryer-Cycling-Thermostat.htm?SourceCode=12&ModelNum=IGD4400VQ1)

Comment: What is that component? What does it do?  What should the reading be?? Just a few of the questions you need to know before replacing parts.

Comment: I have no clue sorry. I suppose randomly measuring things isn't the wisest thing here. I will see what info I can find.

Comment: @JACK I have updated the post to include the dryer model and the component I believe to be what is in the picture. It is a Dryer Cycling Thermostat. atm I have no clue what the reading should be.

Comment: hm. ok. researching more it seems it is used to control heat settings. guess I need to find something else causing the issue.

Comment: Do you have a schematic?  Check the switch on the door that turns the dryer off if you open the door while it's running. It's a popular trouble spot.

Comment: yeah, that bit controls the heat,  if you're not getting noise the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: The part you have identified is a "HEAT CYCLING THERMOSTAT".  The key specs on the letters "L155-25F".  This means it should OPEN at 155F and then close again 25F below that at 130F.  It also contains an over-temperature limit cutoff so that if the dryer gets too hot (usually 200F or so) it will shut off the heat.